# Change dependency version number in multi project gradle build

Tags: maven, gradle, publish, ivy, artifacts

I have a multi module gradle project which contains `core` and `client`. `client` depends on `core` which is declared like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':core')
}
```

If I publish `core` and `client` to Ivy or Maven the dependency from `client` to `core` uses the exact version that is currently defined for the `core` (e.g. `1.0.0`).

Is there a way to change that? Let's say the `core` is guaranteed to be compatible between minor releases. So instead of `1.0.0` i'd like the dependency to be to version `1.+`.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:modifying_the_generated_pom

Comment: Then don't hesitate to put your solution in an answer.

Comment: I wonder why do you want to do that, as they are tightly coupled between the multiple modules.

Comment: @chenrui Like I said the modules are guaranteed to be compatible between major versions. So you don't have to update the client to use a newer version of the core (within one major). With the fixed version numbers this would not be possible. Furthermore the `core` and `client` example is just an example. The real project has many more modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to replace the version in the generated pom.xml I created a helper function:

```
// helper function to replace dependency version in maven pom.xml
def replaceDependencyVersion(root, groupId, artifactId, version) {
    // replace version
    root.dependencies.dependency.findAll() { node ->
        node.groupId.text() == groupId && node.artifactId.text() == artifactId
    }.each() { node ->
        node.version*.value = version
    }
}
```

This function can then be used in publishing to replace the version number:

```
// publishing
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            pom.withXml {
                replaceDependencyVersion(asNode(), 'com.test', 'core', '1.+')
            }
        }
    }
}
```